# Comparing two datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I'm using win forms, and I have 2 datagridviews (with Key and Value cells) and 2 textboxes.
I want the datagrids to do a comparing work, to check if the first datagrid has exactly the same values as the other.
Everytime the client changes his selection in grid, the same key will be selected in the other grid.
The text boxes are to view the full value for each key selection.

My code is doing it but with the index number, so if I have the same keys in the 2 grids but in a different order, it doesn;t showing the correct row.

```
private void dgvSource_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvSource.CurrentRow.Index >= 0 && dgvTemplate.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            dgvTemplate.Rows[dgvSource.CurrentRow.Index].Selected = true;
            rtbTemplateValue.Text = dgvTemplate.Rows[dgvSource.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            rtbTemplateValue.Text = "";
        }

        rtbSourceValue.Text = dgvSource.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    }
}

private void dgvTemplate_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvTemplate.Rows.Count > 0)
        rtbTemplateValue.Text = dgvTemplate.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
}
```

Also, doing a quick QA on my app, I found that sometimes I have some keysfrom the first gris that won't exist in the second grid after loading that data. I need to solve that one too.

Comment: You need to check index/selection by using not the `gridview` but the `dataview` that the `gridview` uses to display data

Comment: sorry, I can't understand what you trying to say. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: You're trying to work your way trough the grid. This is a mistake. Behind your grid there is [probably] `dataTable`. When you say [abstractly] grid.selectedRowIndex, this index may not be the same as row in `DataTable` because you grid works through the `DataView`. `DataTable.DefaultView`, unless you specified yours. So, work with the `DataView` indexing system, not the table, not the grid. You need to read-up on data views